# what is the purpose of the fiberglass mat we get with some vacuum chambers?

Tags: vacuum

I just bought a vacuum chamber which comes with a little square weaved fiberglass mat with some silicone rubber on it's border, and I can't find any information about it's use. Even in the comment people tell the don't know what it's for.

Can anyone tell about it ?
[image]

Comment: "Even in the comment people tell the don't know what it's for" ? What?

Comment: If I had that, I would use it to dry small piles of loose materials like powders and chips and junk. I wonder if it's not just a filter to stop material from getting sucked through the pipe.

Comment: this may, or may not help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=silpat+baking+mat&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either for the chamber to sit on, to avoid contact with the support surface for heat or noise transfer or to sit inside the chamber so any object placed inside is not in contact with the base.

Notice the corners have been cut off, so perhaps inside is more likely.

Comment: It 'appears you've been right : It seems to be about facilitating gas circulation between a bottom flat or cup surface and the base.